# image data go beyond 0-1 range after processing

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am randomly adjusting brightness, saturation etc. of an image. But after adjustment, `img_data` has value beyond 0-1, such that `imshow` will not work.

```
tf.InteractiveSession()
image_raw_data=tf.read_file('C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Neural_Network\\cat.jpg')
sess=tf.Session()
img_data=tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw_data,channels=3)
img_data=tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_data,dtype=tf.float32)
img_data=tf.image.resize_images(img_data,[300,300],method=0)
img_data=tf.image.random_brightness(img_data,max_delta=32/255)
plt.imshow(img_data.eval())
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.
```

May I know how should I properly transform the image so that it can be shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i would do is purely to visualize the image is to add the minimum value in the image and then divide by the maximum value to clamp the image between 0 and 1 in the following fashion:

```
import numpy as np
img_data_np = img_data.eval()
min_val = np.min(img_data_np)
max_val = np.max(img_data_np)
img_data_clamped = (img_data_np - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
plt.imshow(img_data_clamped)
```